# What does "working threat" mean?

Tags: meaning

It is from [Crash Course World History](https://youtu.be/1PLBmUVYYeg). It is at around 10 minute and 28 second. Here is the context:

> Then you have modern endemic diseases like HIV/AIDS along with the working threat of new and terrifying epidemics like the various flus we often hear about.

I checked the adjective *working* in a few dictionaries, and what I saw is that it has not so many definitions, but still I cannot get what the host mean by that.

Comment: I think he's actually saying **lurking** threat.  He isn't the clearest speaker, though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has misheard the speaker in the video.

Comment: In subtitles it was also working

Comment: That doesn't mean much, Dmytro. There are subtitle errors all the time.

Comment: For clarity, I don't think @Tᴚoɯɐuo voted to close because he thought you should have known better, or anything like that, but that sometimes a question just doesn't have any wide applicability, and it isn't necessarily anyone's fault. There's an analogous close reason on Stack Overflow for typos and non-reproducible errors, where the typo might be very hard to spot indeed, but have no relation to any other typos, at least not that can be described in text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine it's either a complete mistake, or he took something like this sentence:

> "Working threat investigations in a military environment is challenging"

or this sentence:

> "The training will teach staff how to create a working threat model"

and then, while preparing the "copypasta" to be served up in his video, slipped up and interpreted 'working threat' as one. (This is not entirely unrealistic: *'X investigations in a military environment is challenging'* is nearly a grammatical sentence, and '*The training will teach staff how to create an X model'* is completely grammatical, so the semantics may have gotten overruled.)

'Working threat' does not make sense in the sentence he utters.

Just for completeness' sake: The above sentences should be parsed as: 'Working **on** threat investigations...' and '... to create a working model of threat'.

Comment: +1 for "'Working threat' does not make sense in the sentence he utters."   Not sure I can commend you for "copypasta" though :)